# Laravel groupBy on particular column

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm running a Laravel 8 project on PHP 7.4. I have a table called `add_ons` and a model called `Addon`. A `Addon` model has a column called `group`, which is how I'd like to group certain rows together under one object, when I try to use the `groupBy` method on my model I get this error:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'domainmonitor_db.add_ons.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause

What am I missing to achieve the grouped functionality I desire?

```php
/**
 * Handle the incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function __invoke(Request $request)
{
    $addons = Addon::groupBy('group')->get();
}
```

[image]

Comment: The answer below contains a lot of useful information, so I'm not putting this as an answer, but rather a comment: in `config/database.php`, check your Connection's `'strict'` setting. If it is `'strict' => true,`, I find a lot of `groupBy()` statements fail with a similar error. You _can_ set this to `'strict' => false,`, but read up on any downsides to this, specifically for your DB engine (`MySQL` vs `Postgres`, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Some database systems -- PostgreSQL in particular -- require that **all** columns `SELECT`-ed in a query with a `GROUP BY` be aggregate columns.

The reason for this is data correctness; say you had multiple rows with a different value in a column that WASN'T the "group by" column (e.g. `SELECT group_id, name from items GROUP BY group_id`) -- what should the DBMS say is the value of the column in the squashed row? It cannot know that, and the DBMS shouldn't guess. *Furthermore, by guessing what should go in that column instead of enforcing this, MySQL gives back garbage data for queries with a group clause.*

When you use a bare `[Model]::groupBy()` it's querying all columns (i.e. a `SELECT * FROM...`) many of which may not be aggregated columns.

You state you want a single object for the grouped records, but there are some unanswered questions:

- What columns should there be?
- If, say, `stripe_id` is part of the object, which row should it come from?

What you may find useful instead is the `Illuminate\Support\Collection` interface's `groupBy()` method, which merely organizes the objects by a common column, and doesn't squash any data:

```php
$collection = Addons::query()->get();
$grouped_collection = $collection->groupBy('group');
```